# "Listen to device" Autohotkey need advice to finish

Tags: windows-8, audio, script, autohotkey, microphone

In all honesty I have no idea what I'm doing and I could really use some help 
I'm trying to turn "Listen to microphone" on and off with the use of the "end" key and have a desktop shortcut. I've done abit but I just need some help finishing. 
To do the process manually it consists of

Control panel > Hardware and sound > manage audio devices > recording > Microphone (only one in list) > Properties > Listen > Listen to this device .

I do this process upwards of 15 times a day and its driving me crazy.
This is what I have so far

Run, mmsys.cpl

WinWait,Sound

Send, {CTRL DOWN}{TAB}{CTRL UP}

ControlSend,SysListView321,{Down}

ControlClick,&Properties

winwait Properties

winwait mircophone properties

I would really appreciate any help

Answer (score 3):

make an file Toggle.ini and fill it with name of device that needs to be toggled on and off ("Listen to this device" checkbox)

I've compiled this to an exe:
Works perfectly for my case...
PC (Windows 10) Wouldn't get into sleep or hibernate and powercfg requestsoverride didnt work so i made this.

```
#SingleInstance
#NoTrayIcon

isExist:=WinExist("ahk_exe rundll32.exe ahk_class #32770")
Run, % "rundll32.exe shell32.dll,Control_RunDLL mmsys.cpl,,recording",,, uPID
WinWait, % "ahk_pid"uPID,, 1

WinWait,Sound

Send {CTRL DOWN}{Down}{CTRL UP}

ControlGet, List, List,, SysListView321, % "ahk_pid"uPID

FileRead, OutputVar, toggle.ini

Loop, Parse, List, `n
{
    IfInString, A_LoopField, %OutputVar%
    {
        ControlClick,&Properties
        Send {CTRL DOWN}{Tab}{CTRL UP}
        Send {Space}
        Send {Enter}
        break
    }
    else 
    {
        ControlSend,SysListView321,{Down}
    }
}

WinWait,Sound
Send {Esc}

ExitApp
```

Hope it can helps somebody...

Answer (score 0):

```
#KeyHistory, 0
ListLines, Off
SetBatchLines, -1

End::
   isExist:=WinExist("ahk_exe rundll32.exe ahk_class #32770")
   Run, % "rundll32.exe shell32.dll,Control_RunDLL mmsys.cpl,,recording",,, uPID
   WinWait, % "ahk_pid"uPID,, 1
   If Not ErrorLevel
   {
      SendInput, {Down}
      ControlClick, % "Button3", % "ahk_pid"uPID,,, 3
      WinWait, % "A"
      PostMessage, 0x1330, 1,, % "SysTabControl321", % "ahk_pid"uPID
      WinWait, % "A"
      ControlGet, isEnabled, Checked,, % "Button1", % "ahk_pid"uPID
      Control, % isEnabled ? "UnCheck":"Check",, % "Button1", % "ahk_pid"uPID
      ControlClick, % "Button9", % "ahk_pid"uPID,,, 3
      Process, Close, % uPID
   }
   IfEqual, ErrorLevel, % True, MsgBox, % 2621 (isExist ? 92:60)
                                      , % isExist ? "Info:":"Oops:"
                                      , % isExist ? "Close other window":"Something went wrong!"
                                      , % isExist ? 1.5:3
   KeyWait, % A_ThisHotkey
   Exit, uPID:=isEnabled:=isExist:=""
```